# How to Use Raw Data in Guzzle with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, api, codeigniter-3, guzzle

I'm using Guzzle 7 in Codigniter 3. I'm trying to send a GET request to another server using raw data. What I mean is something like the one in the picture.
[image: raw data in Postman]

But so far, I've been only receiving error from the server.
Message: Client error: `GET 'http://localhost:8080/MyGateway/MyAPI/v1/f1' resulted in a` 400 Bad Request` response:

This is my code:

```php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $res1 = $client->request(
            'GET',
            'http://localhost:8080/MyGateway/MyAPI/v1/f1',
            [
            'auth' => ['admins','admins'],
            'headers' => [
                'my-token ' => $token,
                'my-opt '   => 'getStatus',
                'Content-Type'=> 'text/plain'
                ],
            'body' => '{ "ID":"1282158" }',
            'debug' => true
            ]
        );
```

And this is the Generated code for cURL

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/MyGateway/MyAPI/v1/f1' \
--header 'my-token: a_mytoken_c' \
--header 'my-opt: getStatus' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic Y_Auth_l' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
  "ID":"1282158"
}'
```

Edit: I've tried adding 'debug' => true up there. And now I have this error.

> Message: curl_setopt_array(): cannot represent a stream of type Output
> as a STDIO FILE*

I've also tried using cURL from Postman and it works completely fine. SO, cURL works fine, but Guzzle gives me error.

My API uses both an authentication and also a randomly generated token that I've set to my own page. I've tried using form-params instead of body and it still showed the same error. I've tried using Postman with that raw data and headers setting and it works. Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to use `content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: I've tried that, it still says the same tho. I've changed the  'Content-Type'=> 'text/plain'
 to  'Content-Type'=> 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8' Still the same error. @bhucho

Comment: can you show a screenshot how you are sending it via postman, showing all the params & headers you can hide the private data just show how you are sending a correct request, you can also show a curl request

Comment: if your body is json, you can try to just let guzzle handle the json encoding `'body' => json_encode(["ID" => "1282158"])`

Comment: Okay, I added the cURL code.

Comment: is your guzzle version less than 6 as the syntax may be different?

Comment: It's version 7. Am I using an outdated syntax?

Comment: no syntax is for the newer version, if syntax is not the problem I suggest to use [debug](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#debug) as true as request options, also use [on_stats](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#on-stats) to check what are the stats store the data in log, the code you have posted looks ok